Uploading Products on vue+php project

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'branch_products.catal ogue_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count() as aggregate from (select branch_products. from branch_products inner join vendors on vendors.id = branch_products.vendor_id left join catalogues on catalogues.id = branch_products.catal ogue_id where ((date(catalogues.start_date) <= 2024-05-09 and date(catalogues.end_date) >= 2024-05-09) or catalogues.while_stock_last = true) and vendors.status = active and branch_products.status = deleted group by branch_products.id) as aggregate_table)

I'm trying to upload a product on the my website (vue+php) but it's giving the error as mentioned above when connected to database (large) of the live website but it is able to upload properly on the local version of the database (smaller) although the structure and everything is literally the same . it is supposed to post image of the product onto the home page. what could be the issue here?

Is that space in catal ogue_id intentional?  This looks like just a typo.

where can I locate the query (the file in php) to find that typo?

I don't see how anybody here would know that.  We can't see your code.  Presumably the error indicates a line number and file name, which is a good place to start.
